# Waiting for all tasks to complete in Threadpool

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, task, threadpool

I need help with this code, so if anyone is willing to help I would be grateful.

I'm working on developing a simple thread pool, which is passed an array of numbers, and the threads compute the factorial of each number in parallel. What the problem is in my code, what if for example I have two threads and I have six tasks. Two threads take a task, complete it, and the program ends there. What I want is for them to take the task, do it, if there are more tasks, start new tasks and do them, and the program ends only when all the tasks are completed.

Here is my code:

MyThreadPool.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ThreadPool
{
    public class MyThreadPool : IDisposable
    {
        private bool _disposed = false;

        private object _lock = new object();

        private Queue<MyTask> tasks = new();

        public MyThreadPool(int numThreads = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    while (_disposed == false)
                    {

                        MyTask? task;
                        lock (_lock)
                        {
                            while (!tasks.TryDequeue(out task) && _disposed == false)
                            {
                                Monitor.Wait(_lock);
                            }
                        }
                        if (task != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@$"Thread {Thread.CurrentThread
                                .ManagedThreadId} calculated factorial for {task
                                .getNum()}. Result: {task.CalculateFactorial(task
                                .getNum())}");
                            lock (_lock)
                            {
                                if (tasks.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).Start();
            }
        }

        public MyTask Enqueue(int number)
        {
            MyTask task = new(number);
            lock (_lock)
            {
                tasks.Enqueue(task);
                Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
            }
            return task;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _disposed = true;
            lock (_lock)
            {
                Monitor.PulseAll(_lock);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyTask.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ThreadPool
{
    public class MyTask
    {
        private int num;

        public void setNum(int num)
        {
            this.num = num;
        }

        public int getNum()
        {
            return this.num;
        }

        public MyTask(int number)
        {
            this.num = number;
        }

        public int CalculateFactorial(int number)
        {
            int result = 1;
            for (int i = number; i > 0; i--)
            { 
                result = result * i;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int numThread = 3;
int x = 0;
MyThreadPool threadPool = new(numThread);;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    threadPool.Enqueue(array[i]);
}

threadPool.Dispose();
```

Comment: Threadpools aren't simple and .NET already has a very well built and easy to use threadpool and Tasks. Threadpools don't use locks and monitors to perform their work either. They don't use thread-unsafe collections for buffering. What's the point of this code?

Comment: Yes, but I need it here for education, to understand how threads work.

Comment: You don't learn about cars by trying to implement a jet engine. .NET is open source which means you can find and inspect the threadpool code itself.

Comment: My biggest problem here is that not all tasks are done, but a thread takes a task, completes it and most likely _disposed is set to true, and then all threads are called to complete their work because _disposed = true.

Comment: If anyone is willing to help, this has been bothering me for days.

Comment: What you posted isn't a thread pool, it's a queue with workers, using unsafe classes. If you want to see how .NET's ThreadPool works, you can inspect the [source code itself](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs)

Comment: You are trying to reinvent not only the `ThreadPool` class, but also the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) type. If you are allowed to use the `BlockingCollection<T>`, your chances of ending with a functional `ThreadPool` implementation will increase significantly.

Comment: Please do not use such an implementation for anything you care about. A good rule of thumb is to use the highest level abstraction you can get away with. That means things like BlockingCollection, Task, Parallel.For, etc. I do not want to discourage learning, but if I was attempting something like this I would study the documentation and other resources *extensively*. It is super easy to make mistakes when writing low level multi threaded code like this, and errors might not be apparent, or tell you what went wrong.

Comment: As a side note, you could consider renaming the private fields `tasks` and `num` to `_tasks` and `_num`, for consistency with the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods, since you only use while+moniter to synchronize threads throughout, I only use this method too.

We need a count:

```
private int _incompleteTaskCount = 0;

public MyTask Enqueue(int number)
{
    ....
    lock (_lock)
    {
        tasks.Enqueue(task);
        _incompleteTaskCount++;
        Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
    }
    ....
}

public MyThreadPool(int numThreads = 0)
{
    ....
    lock (_lock)
    {
        _incompleteTaskCount--;
        // if (tasks.Count > 0)
        // {
            Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
        // }
    }
    ....
}
```

Then you can wait till `_incompleteTaskCount` becomes 0.

```
public void WaitForComplete()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        while (_incompleteTaskCount > 0)
        {
            Monitor.Wait(_lock);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the difference between the `_incompleteTaskCount` and the `tasks.Count`?

Comment: I guess that "complete" mentioned in the title refers to the completion of all `Console.WriteLine` calls. But `tasks.Count` will be 0 after this line: `tasks.TryDequeue(out task)`.